# How to share file between two android devices using Socket programming?

Tags: android, eclipse, client-server, serversocket

I am new in android development i am trying to share files between two android device using socket programming

I have the code which sends text between server and client but i am trying to send images or other files from client device to server

Here my code goes
Server Side Code

```
public void run() {
OutputStream outputStream;


String msgReply = "Hello from Android, you are #" + cnt;
try {
outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
         PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
         printStream.print(msgReply);
         printStream.close();

message += "replayed: " + msgReply + "\n";

MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

 @Override
 public void run() {
  msg.setText(message);
 }
});



}
catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";


}
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
 msg.setText(message);
}


});}
```

Client Side Code

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


String dstAddress;


int dstPort;


String response = "";
MyClientTask(String addr, int port){


dstAddress = addr;


  dstPort = port;


 }

@Override


  protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {



Socket socket = null;
try {
socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = 
              new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int bytesRead;
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

/*
 * notice:
 * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
 */
         while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
             byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
             response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
         }



}
catch (UnknownHostException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();


}
catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
response = "IOException: " + e.toString();


}
finally{
if(socket != null){
 try {
  socket.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}


}
 return null;


}
 @Override


protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

 textResponse.setText(response);
super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

Thanks